# Google Forms cannot be opened by Custom Google Drive application

Tags: google-drive-api, mime-types

I have create a Google Drive application that needs to open Google Forms. If I try to add the type "application/vnd.google-apps.form" as "Secondary MIME Types" in the console API project, I get the following error message : "MIME types beginning with "application/vnd.google-apps." are reserved for internal use. If you want your app to open Google documents, use the import option below"

I have activated the "Allow users to open files that can be converted to a format that this app can open" option, but, when I rigth click on a Google Form from Google Drive, my application is not listed in the "Open with" submenu

Do you have any explanation ?
Thanks for help,

Comment: Try explaining what it is that you want to achieve. If your application could open a form (it can't) what would it do with it?

Answer (score 0):

You cant. It says so right in the error message you get:  "MIME types beginning with "application/vnd.google-apps." are reserved for internal use. If you want your app to open Google documents, use the import option below"

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. As I said, I already activated the "import option" and I can select my Drive application when selecting a Google Docs or a Spreadsheet, but it's not working for Google Form format.